# "meteor npm start " failed (Rocket.Chat)

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I failed to install the app via npm.
I’m on Ubuntu 16.04.
node -v = v5.0.0.
npm -v = 3.5.3.

Here are the errors I get:

> mani@mani-Inspiron-3537:~/sekar/chat/Rocket.Chat$ sudo meteor npm start
>
> Rocket.Chat@0.60.0-develop start /home/mani/sekar/chat/Rocket.Chat 
>   meteor npm i && meteor
>
> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND npm ERR! network
>   request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist/-/yallist-2.1.2.tgz
>   failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
>   registry.npmjs.org:443 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to
>   network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a
>   proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network  npm ERR! network
>   If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network
>   'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/sekar/.npm/_logs/2017-11-15T08_30_47_562Z-debug.log npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Rocket.Chat@0.60.0-develop
>   start: `meteor npm i && meteor` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm
>   ERR! Failed at the Rocket.Chat@0.60.0-develop start script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above.

And Internet is also working fine

> mani@mani-Inspiron-3537:~/sekar/chat/Rocket.Chat$ ping
>   registry.npmjs.org
>
> PING a.sni.fastly.net (151.101.8.162) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> 64 bytes from 151.101.8.162: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=36.5 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 151.101.8.162: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=35.8 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 151.101.8.162: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=36.2 ms
>
> --- a.sni.fastly.net ping statistics ---
>
> 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms rtt
>   min/avg/max/mdev = 35.894/36.248/36.590/0.28

4 ms

Please give solution for this error.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you were connected to the internet at the time. Looks like a connection issue.

Comment: internet is working fine

Comment: CAn you hit this link https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist/-/yallist-2.1.2.tgz manually from your browser?

Comment: link is also working

Comment: Is it possible you are behind a proxy? try setting npm to work with http instead of https.  `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"` .

Comment: proxy also correct but still not working